# Images not correctly displayed using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm setting an application where I need to display some image. My images are located outside of my app's folder, that's why I've used this:

```py
    @app.route('/<path:filename>')
    def download_file(filename):
          return send_from_directory(MEDIA_FOLDER, filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
```

The architecture of my folders is:

```py
--images1
  |__ image1.png
  |__ image2.png
--images2
  |__ image3.png
  |__ image4.png
--web
  |__ app.py
  |__ templates
    |__ index.html
```

I've stored all my images path in a list as:

`images_path = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', ...]`

At the moment, I've tried to display the images as:

```html
{% for image in images_path %}

<img src="{{ url_for('download_file', filename="{{ image }}") }}">
```

Using this, it displays always the same image. In my example the `image1.png`.
I've tried to check if the for loop works, and it works.

I've tried this:

```html
{{ image }} CHECKER
<img src="{{ url_for('download_file', filename="{{ image }}") }}">
```

and it displays on my page:

```
>>> 

image1.png CHECKER then the `image1.png`

image2.png CHECKER but also `image1.png`
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

In my app.py, I've added this:

```
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
images_folder = [images1, images2]
try:
    for image_folder in imagesfolder:
        MEDIA_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))) + str(image_folder) + "\\"
            return send_from_directory(MEDIA_FOLDER, filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            abort(404)
```

and on my template.html, I've added this:

```html
{% for image in images_path %}

<img src="{{ url_for('download_file', filename=image) }}">
```

How can I correctly set the path here?
How can I link the images and its directory?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I've changed my script by:

```py
    @app.route('/<path:filename>')
    def download_file(filename):
        try:
            return send_file(filename, as_attachment=True)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            abort(404)
```

The filename will be defined by:

```
>>>> filename = str(os.getcwd()) + str(list_machine[i]) + str(elem)
```

When I inspect the elements on my page, the URL seems to be right but the image is not displayed.

---

How can I display all the images stored in my folders?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to replace `{{ image }}` by this: `image`

Comment: It actually works but if I add new images, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('download_file', filename=image) }}">
```

with the `image` variable defined as: `image = str(os.getcwd()) + '/path/to/image'`

You must define this variable by listing your files, you can use: `os.listdir('path/directory')`.

Your function named `download_file` should be:

```
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    try:
        filename=os.path.join(app.root_path, filename)
        return send_file(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
```

Don't forget to import the `send_file` function.

It works for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: My path was not correctly defined, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't come from {{ image }} but I don't see in your code {% endfor %} after the html img.

So the correct code is :

```
{% for image in images_path %}
<img src="{{ url_for('download_file', filename="{{ image }}") }}">
{% endfor %}
```

UPDATE 1:

I think you make several mistakes in your code :

```
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    images_folder = ['images1', 'images2']
    MEDIA_FOLDER = []
    try:
        for image_folder in imagesfolder:
            MEDIA_FOLDER.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))) + str(image_folder) + "\\")
                return send_from_directory(MEDIA_FOLDER, filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned it on my example but I've added the `{% endfor %}`. When I removed the `{{ }}` it actually works on my local machine but not on my server.

Comment: I obtain some really special output, when I add another image to my folder, the old images are displayed but not the new one.

Comment: If you can send more code it will be really helpful

Comment: Thanks for your update, I solve my issue by using another function from Flask called send_file(). Now my script works on my local machine but it still doesn't work on my server, the files are not found because of the path. `/script/user%5images%images1.png`. When I move to Linux my path is not readable, do you know why? What is these `%5` in the path?

Comment: It is the slash encoding by the url, I advise you to have a look at one of my project which uses sendfile in flask in a linux server [Flask sendfile and files generator](https://github.com/emiledelmas/Website_Docx_Generator) and up my answer if it was helful :)

Comment: I've tried to look on your scripts but I didn't find a way to solve this. Some of my files cannot be loaded even a css file that I've created. `static/css/script.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)`